# Issues running Script to install EXE on remote machines

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to run a PowerShell script to install an exe remotely on a list of machines which I import as a CSV. I have copied the exe to the same location on all machines and I was orignally getting an executtion policy error which I have now resolved but now the exe fails to install.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force -Scope LocalMachine -WhatIf
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\test.csv"

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $Server = $row.server
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\TEMP\Apps\ActiveX\ActXPack.EXE"
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Do you get any errors?  Does the EXE expect user input, or maybe need some parameters to be silent?  Does it connect to anything external?  Note that the `-WhatIf` switch is a kind of 'try before you buy' thing and in fact means that `Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet won't actually set the policy.

Comment: We have a custom active X package that runs and installs silently just running the exe, I can get it to work no problem for a msi but when I amend the script for the exe i get a message saying the path cant be found. Thanks for the info about the whatif statement. I built the set-exceution policy using the command builder and for some reason the only way it would work is with the what if.